# Data lost at update

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Everytime I click Update when I open the Excel document the data is lost. I link to some external documents. If I open those documents the data reappears.
The formula with the link looks something like this:

```
=SUMIF('\\adress\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\[Linia1.xls]BD'!$A$2:$A$65536,A19,'\\address\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\[Linia1.xls]BD'!$AR$2:$AR$65536)
```

Comment: I think this is the standard behavior of Excel formula with external data. Maybe you should try `GetInfoFromClosedFile()` as suggested in one of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401967/copy-data-from-another-workbook-through-vba/

Comment: GetInfoFromClosedFile() might work but I'm not using VBA in this one.

Comment: Maybe you could try a UDF? But I'm not sure that would be enough...

Answer (score 0):

Though it is annoying, it is not a bug but a feature as JMax suggested.
To make your life more convenient you could consider adding a few hyperlinks to the workbooks that need to be open.