# vba multiple sheets conflict

Tags: vba, excel

I am opening 4 different xlsm files that ran a macro. 
The macro reads data from the cells. 
The macros work individually but together they get messed up. 
because

```
Cells(1, 1).Value
```

is taken from the active sheet and not from the sheet I want .

Is there anyway to spicify a sheet like

```
workbook("example1").sheet("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
workbook("example2").sheet("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
```

?

Edit : (thanks Gimp)
I tried

```
Dim oWorkSheet As Worksheet    
Set oWorkSheet = Workbooks("example1.xlsm").Sheets("sheet1")
    oWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
```

and got a run time error

```
"Object doesn't support this property and method"
```

Comment: Are the files opened by the macro?

Comment: Consider using Excel Object model as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7402165/649687

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is a very common problem if you do not fully qualify your object. Let's take an example. If we have 4 workbooks and all four have Sheet called "Sheet1" then how should we ensure that the data is picked up from the right cell?

```
Cells(1, 1).Value
```

will always pick up the data from the current active sheet which might not be the sheet that you actually want.

If you are opening the 4 files via macro then this is the right way of doing it.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook, wb4 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\File1.xlsx")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\File2.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open("C:\File3.xlsx")
    Set ws3 = wb3.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set wb4 = Workbooks.Open("C:\File4.xlsx")
    Set ws4 = wb4.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Now you can work with the relevant cells
    Debug.Print ws1.Cells(1, 1).Value
    Debug.Print ws2.Cells(1, 1).Value
    Debug.Print ws3.Cells(1, 1).Value
    Debug.Print ws4.Cells(1, 1).Value
End Sub
```

If you are not opening the four files via macro you can still set them to wb1, wb2 etc and then work as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use:

```
workbooks("example1.xlsm").sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
workbooks("example2.xlsm").sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
```

**Update**
Its either your workbook or sheet name that isnt working.

try `msgbox Workbooks("example1.xlsm").name` If that works then your problem is likely with the `sheets()` section. If it doesnt, then you may need to fully qualify the section like `Workbooks("C:/Folder1/example1.xlsm")`

Comment: I tried that =>Set oWorkSheet = Workbooks("RT_stocks.xlsm").Sheets("stocks")