# VBA How to display records or data in different worksheet in a single excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I just know how to display the records in a worksheet,for example  A,it connect to the view created in db, but now i want to display another records in another worksheet which is B .Different records but in the same excel file. And it will display the records at the same time when i open the excel file. So please help on how to code in VB script(workbook) .thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused. can't you just type = in B, go to A, and select the record you want to import?

Comment: Actually i new in vba ,i not sure what other things can be done with vba, actually what i want is just how to display different data or records in different worksheet

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401967/copy-data-from-another-workbook-through-vba. if you are spending time to learn vba, I recommend trying another scripting language at the same time. personally, switching from vba to python was quite liberating...

Comment: i need to use vba in this..based on the link i need to open another workbook?open one more excel file ?i display the data using SQL, different worksheet show different record in different sql