# Change the type of data

Tags: excel, vba

I want to blend the data from two files into one single excel sheet
the visual basic code must import the two sheets into one.

What I want to do is changing the data types of that different data in order for them to fit in the same column.

For example :
FILE A

```
col A | col B
int(2)|int(4)
```

FILE B

```
col A | col B
int(5)| int(2)
```

must blend into

File C

```
col A | col B
int(3)| int(3)
```

how to do this kind of script? No idea where to start.
The data type could be anything not just int, i just want them to be defined somewhere in the code.

edit :

The content from file A and file B must appear in file C
The column A from file A and B must go to file C in a column also called A with all the data from fileA:A and fileB:A

Comment: What do you mean by blending in? I dont get that part.

Comment: As Tom mentioned, can you give more detail as to how you want the columns blended (aka merged I assume)? For example is File C's colA = FileAcolA & FileBcolB or sometimes col A from file a and sometimes the one from file b based on content?

Comment: I just edited my message, can you take the minus back if it's ok now?

Comment: As Bryan said - how does **int(2)** and **int(5)** get 'blended' to equal **int(3)**?
If all the data from file A & B must appear in the same column in file C surely  you'd expect it to be **int(2)int(5)**?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what you want but here is some code and a link to get you started. The code I will be using is a trimmed down version that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401967/copy-data-from-another-workbook-through-vba) or [here](http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbawbreadfromclosedwb). The code below gets data from the xlsx files without opening them and combines the two sets of column data with a comma.

```
Dim FileAColA As Variant
Dim FileAColB As Variant
Dim FileBColA As Variant
Dim FileBColB As Variant
Dim arg As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 2

'Gets data from FileA col a then b then same for fileB
arg = "'C:\Workspace\trash\[FileA.xlsx]Sheet1'!R" & i & "C1"
FileAColA = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
arg = "'C:\Workspace\trash\[FileA.xlsx]Sheet1'!R" & i & "C2"
FileAColB = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
arg = "'C:\Workspace\trash\[FileB.xlsx]Sheet1'!R" & i & "C1"
FileBColA = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
arg = "'C:\Workspace\trash\[FileB.xlsx]Sheet1'!R" & i & "C2"
FileBColB = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)

'While loop to continue until no data in all 4 cells, when no data in cell varient will be 0
While FileAColA <> 0 And FileAColB <> 0 And FileBColA <> 0 And FileBColB <> 0
    Cells(i, 1).Value = FileAColA & "," & FileBColA 'Combines values with a comma in between
    Cells(i, 2).Value = FileAColB & "," & FileBColB 'Combines values with a comma in between

    i = i + 1

    'Gets data from FileA col a then b then same for fileB
    arg = "'C:\Workspace\trash\[FileA.xlsx]Sheet1'!R" & i & "C1"
    FileAColA = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
    arg = "'C:\Workspace\trash\[FileA.xlsx]Sheet1'!R" & i & "C2"
    FileAColB = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
    arg = "'C:\Workspace\trash\[FileB.xlsx]Sheet1'!R" & i & "C1"
    FileBColA = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
    arg = "'C:\Workspace\trash\[FileB.xlsx]Sheet1'!R" & i & "C2"
    FileBColB = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
Wend
```

If you don't want them to combine with a comma and instead want to add them together then instead of *FileAColA & "," & FileBColA* you can do *FileAColA + FileBColA*. If you want them combined in some other way, you will have to explain in more detail and preferably include examples of before and after column data.