# Getting data from closed workbook and assigning to a variable

Tags: excel, vba, excel-4.0

I am using the code below to retrieve a number from a closed workbook. The `MsgBox` returns the correct value but I am unable to assign that number to my `modelVersion` variable and don't understand why this is the case. I would appreciate if someone can help me out as I figure that the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` method maybe can't be used in this way?

```
Public Sub checkModelVersion()
    
    Dim wbPath As String, wbName As String
    Dim wsName As String, cellRef As String
    Dim Ret As String

    wbPath = "C:\mypath\"

    wbName = "Update.xlsm"
    wsName = "Dashboard"
    cellRef = "E7"

    Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

    MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)
    modelVersion = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is modelVersion declared outside your sub in a module?

Comment: I guess you are not able to get data from a closed workbook. You have to open it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy data from another Workbook through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401967/copy-data-from-another-workbook-through-vba)